# Symfony 3 - Swiftmailer not sending email

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, symfony-3.4

I'm attempting to send an email using SwiftMailer (version = Swift-5.4.8) after a user submits a form.  I cannot determine why the email is not being sent.  I have only tried using gmail setup as I've heard it is easiest to use (am new to web dev).

I have tried changing config.yml, parameters.yml

#### parameters.yml:

```
    parameters:
        database_host: 127.0.0.1
        database_port: null
        database_name: symfony
        database_user: root
        database_password: null
        mailer_transport: gmail
        mailer_encryption: ssl
        mailer_auth_mode: login
        mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
        mailer_user: myemail@gmail.com
        mailer_password: mypass
        secret: mysecret
```

#### config.yml (relevant snippet, please lmk if need other portions)

```
    swiftmailer:
        transport: '%mailer_transport%'
        host: '%mailer_host%'
        username: '%mailer_user%'
        password: '%mailer_password%'
        spool: { type: memory }
```

#### DefaultController

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('from', EmailType::class)
        ->add('message', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('send',SubmitType::class)
        ->getForm()
    ;

    if ($form->isSubmitted()){
        $data = $form->getData();

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
            ->setSubject('Join Our Team Request')
            ->setFrom($data['from'])
            ->setTo('myemail2@gmail.com')
            ->setBody(
                $data['message'],'text/plain'
            )
        ;

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
    }

    return $this->render('xxx.html.twig', array("title" => "...","join_team_form" =>$form->createView()));
```

The view and form are rendered correctly.  It appears the form submits correctly, however I never receive an email. Again new to web dev, any suggestions appreciated.

EDIT: I was able to successfully configure and send an email using the command prompt and the 'php bin\console swiftmailer:email:send' command.  The issue was it was using a dev_config file, silly error.  However, when I still fill out the form and click the send button, no email gets sent.  Only using the above command.  Any insight?

EDIT2: Solution to first EDIT was running 'composer update'.... nice...

Comment: Did you setup your gmail account?

Comment: Yes email account was created a while back

Answer (score 0):

Try to use tls encryption and smtp tranport protocol.
Your config.yml will be similar to this:

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: 'smtp'
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com'
    username: 'myemail@gmail.com'
    password: 'mypass'
    encryption: tls
    auth_mode: login
```

And, you must activate access to less secure applications and disable two step authentification in your gmail account.

Comment: Gmail transport type sets everything up for you so your configuration is unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to send mails with gmail on Symfony is described in [this documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html#using-gmail-to-send-emails)

But for this you need to have environment variables loaded in your application, and I don't know it's your case.

The below should work. Update your `config.yml` to

```
swiftmailer:
    url: 'gmail://%mailer_user%:%mailer_password%@localhost?encryption=tls&auth_mode=oauth'
    spool: { type: 'memory' }
```

Another suggestion is to check that your form is valid before sending the mail. Otherwise the send will fail if the `from` is `null` or `""`

```
if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){ ... }
```

Let me know if  it don't work

Comment: I updated config.yml like instructed without any success.  I removed the isValid() portion for debugging purposes but good looking out.  I am wondering if localhost is the culprit.  I will update if I figure out.  Thank you

Comment: Yes, it is currently enabled